# PHP Loop not working for CSV output using MySQL variable

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I created a variable from a MySQL query that gives a total number value of photos available for a record. This along with a few other variables from the query I can use to construct a dynamic URL in a CSV file I am exporting.

**This works great:**

```
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)

  {
      if($name=='MatrixImage') {$jpg_name=$value;}
      if($name=='PhotoCount') {$count_name=$value;}     
      if($name != 'estate_property_gallery')
            $csv_output .= $value."|";


      if($name == 'estate_property_gallery')
    {
      $csv_output .= "http://url/feeds/".$value."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_".$count_name.".jpg";
    }               

  }
```

I need to be able to loop through and create multiple URLs using this PhotoCount variable starting from 1 to the final value found in PhotoCount seperated by a comma but I can't seem to get it right.

**Not working:**

```
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)

  {
      if($name=='MatrixImage') {$jpg_name=$value;}
      if($name=='PhotoCount') {$count_name=$value;}     
      if($name != 'estate_property_gallery')
            $csv_output .= $value."|";


      if($name == 'estate_property_gallery')
    {
      //$csv_output .= "http://url/feeds/".$value."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_".$count_name.".jpg";
      for( $pic_start=1; $pic_start<=$count_name; $pic_start++ ){
    echo '$csv_output .= "http://url/feeds/' . $value . '/rets_images/' . $jpg_name . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg,"';
}
    }               

  }
```

The example above outputs the entire line including the $csv_output to the screen instead of putting each URL into the column of the CSV and delimiting with a comma.

**To clarify:** I need to be able to write this echo into the $csv_output .= portion of the code successfully so I can write multiple URLs separated by a comma within that column in my csv output:

echo 'http://www.myagentsbuddy.com/feeds/' . $value . '/rets_images/' . $jpg_name . '_' . $count_name . '.jpg';

Comment: this => `echo '$csv_output` single quotes don't get parsed. Then a comma in `'.jpg,"` if that is intentional or not, no idea. Then closing in a single quote. Fix that, code should work.

Comment: so basically `echo $csv_output .= "http://url/feeds/' . $value . '/rets_images/' . $jpg_name . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg,";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- still outputs to screen when I update it with this:  echo "$csv_output .= 'url' . $value . '/rets_images/' . $jpg_name . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg|';";

Comment: if `echo "$csv_output .= 'url' . $value . '/rets_images/' . $jpg_name . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg|';";` there's an extra `;` in there after `'`. - but you say it outputs to screen, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: output to screen shows a mangled column too instead of a URLs delimited by a comma.

Comment: Instead of writing a CSV it writes everything to the screen ...its not moving onto the writing of the csv portion'

Comment: you're going to need to edit your question with the code for that "writing to". when something writes code on screen, it's probably a misplaced brace or something. That running file's a `.php` too?

Comment: also your other working file has `.$count_name.".jpg|";` with a `|` for `$csv_output .= $value."|";` same for both codes, but your other one has `'.jpg,"';` as a comma delimiter, while the working one has `".jpg|";` so that could also contribute here.

Comment: The | was a mistake on my part, I updated the question with what I need I think.  The problem is that I need to place the echo into the pre-existing $csv_output .= in order for the for loop to work?  Maybe there is a better way to handle the loop but this is all I can think up.

Comment: Sorry Rocco.... I can't find the solution. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first example you showed works great, and does not include an `echo`, and the second example you showed (with an echo) does not work, it seems like it could be fixed by removing the `echo` and going back to just appending the URLs to the `$csv_output` like you're doing in the working example.

```
if($name == 'estate_property_gallery') {
    $comma = '';
    for( $pic_start=1; $pic_start<=$count_name; $pic_start++ ) {
        $csv_output .= $comma.'http://url/feeds/'.$value.'/rets_images/'
                      .$jpg_name.'_'.$pic_start.'.jpg';
        // doing the comma like this will prevent a trailing comma after the last entry
        $comma = ',';
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much for the help, basically looks like I over-complicated it LOL!